# How to use a string saved in a VAR inside a expression?

Tags: string, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, var

I'm trying to create a table from another using the expression SELECTCOLUMNS.

The expression of each column has a different name, so I tried to use a VAR which saves the string, to use it repeatly in the expression, but seems that SEARCH method inside of it, doesn't like it.

- First column "Security ID" is the expression that runs OK
- Next columns are what I'm trying to do, but it DOESN'T WORK.

How I can achived it? or it's not possible?

PowerBI Desktop expression to create a new table:

```
AzureFileEvents = 
SELECTCOLUMNS (
    query_data,
    "Security ID", 
        VAR fieldName = "Security ID"
        VAR idStart = SEARCH(fieldName, [RenderedDescription], , LEN(fieldName))
        VAR idEnd = SEARCH(" ", [RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName))
        RETURN IF(ISBLANK(idStart), BLANK(), MID([RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName), idEnd - idStart - LEN(fieldName))),
    "Account Name", 
        VAR fieldName = "Account Name"
        VAR idStart = SEARCH(fieldName, [RenderedDescription], , LEN(fieldName))
        VAR idEnd = SEARCH(" ", [RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName))
        RETURN IF(ISBLANK(idStart), BLANK(), MID([RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName), idEnd - idStart - LEN(fieldName))),
    "Account Domain", 
        VAR fieldName = "Account Domain"
        VAR idStart = SEARCH(fieldName, [RenderedDescription], , LEN(fieldName))
        VAR idEnd = SEARCH(" ", [RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName))
        RETURN IF(ISBLANK(idStart), BLANK(), MID([RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName), idEnd - idStart - LEN(fieldName))),
    "Logon ID", 
        VAR fieldName = "Logon ID"
        VAR idStart = SEARCH(fieldName, [RenderedDescription], , LEN(fieldName))
        VAR idEnd = SEARCH(" ", [RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName))
        RETURN IF(ISBLANK(idStart), BLANK(), MID([RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName), idEnd - idStart - LEN(fieldName))),
    "Object Server", 
        VAR fieldName = "Object Server"
        VAR idStart = SEARCH(fieldName, [RenderedDescription], , LEN(fieldName))
        VAR idEnd = SEARCH(" ", [RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName))
        RETURN IF(ISBLANK(idStart), BLANK(), MID([RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName), idEnd - idStart - LEN(fieldName))),
    "Object Type", 
        VAR fieldName = "Object Type"
        VAR idStart = SEARCH(fieldName, [RenderedDescription], , LEN(fieldName))
        VAR idEnd = SEARCH(" ", [RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName))
        RETURN IF(ISBLANK(idStart), BLANK(), MID([RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName), idEnd - idStart - LEN(fieldName))),
    "Object Name", 
        VAR fieldName = "Object Name"
        VAR idStart = SEARCH(fieldName, [RenderedDescription], , LEN(fieldName))
        VAR idEnd = SEARCH(" ", [RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName))
        RETURN IF(ISBLANK(idStart), BLANK(), MID([RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName), idEnd - idStart - LEN(fieldName))),
    "Handle ID", 
        VAR fieldName = "Handle ID"
        VAR idStart = SEARCH(fieldName, [RenderedDescription], , LEN(fieldName))
        VAR idEnd = SEARCH(" ", [RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName))
        RETURN IF(ISBLANK(idStart), BLANK(), MID([RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName), idEnd - idStart - LEN(fieldName))),
    "Resource Attributes", 
        VAR fieldName = "Resource Attributes"
        VAR idStart = SEARCH(fieldName, [RenderedDescription], , LEN(fieldName))
        VAR idEnd = SEARCH(" ", [RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName))
        RETURN IF(ISBLANK(idStart), BLANK(), MID([RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName), idEnd - idStart - LEN(fieldName))),
    "Process Information", 
        VAR fieldName = "Process Information"
        VAR idStart = SEARCH(fieldName, [RenderedDescription], , LEN(fieldName))
        VAR idEnd = SEARCH(" ", [RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName))
        RETURN IF(ISBLANK(idStart), BLANK(), MID([RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName), idEnd - idStart - LEN(fieldName))),
    "Process ID", 
        VAR fieldName = "Process ID"
        VAR idStart = SEARCH(fieldName, [RenderedDescription], , LEN(fieldName))
        VAR idEnd = SEARCH(" ", [RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName))
        RETURN IF(ISBLANK(idStart), BLANK(), MID([RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName), idEnd - idStart - LEN(fieldName))),
    "Process Name", 
        VAR fieldName = "Process Name"
        VAR idStart = SEARCH(fieldName, [RenderedDescription], , LEN(fieldName))
        VAR idEnd = SEARCH(" ", [RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName))
        RETURN IF(ISBLANK(idStart), BLANK(), MID([RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName), idEnd - idStart - LEN(fieldName))),
    "Network Information", 
        VAR fieldName = "Network Information"
        VAR idStart = SEARCH(fieldName, [RenderedDescription], , LEN(fieldName))
        VAR idEnd = SEARCH(" ", [RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName))
        RETURN IF(ISBLANK(idStart), BLANK(), MID([RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName), idEnd - idStart - LEN(fieldName))),
    "Source Address", 
        VAR fieldName = "Source Address"
        VAR idStart = SEARCH(fieldName, [RenderedDescription], , LEN(fieldName))
        VAR idEnd = SEARCH(" ", [RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName))
        RETURN IF(ISBLANK(idStart), BLANK(), MID([RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName), idEnd - idStart - LEN(fieldName))),
    "Source Port", 
        VAR fieldName = "Source Port"
        VAR idStart = SEARCH(fieldName, [RenderedDescription], , LEN(fieldName))
        VAR idEnd = SEARCH(" ", [RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName))
        RETURN IF(ISBLANK(idStart), BLANK(), MID([RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName), idEnd - idStart - LEN(fieldName))),
    "Share Information", 
        VAR fieldName = "Share Information"
        VAR idStart = SEARCH(fieldName, [RenderedDescription], , LEN(fieldName))
        VAR idEnd = SEARCH(" ", [RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName))
        RETURN IF(ISBLANK(idStart), BLANK(), MID([RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName), idEnd - idStart - LEN(fieldName))),
    "Share Name", 
        VAR fieldName = "Share Name"
        VAR idStart = SEARCH(fieldName, [RenderedDescription], , LEN(fieldName))
        VAR idEnd = SEARCH(" ", [RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName))
        RETURN IF(ISBLANK(idStart), BLANK(), MID([RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName), idEnd - idStart - LEN(fieldName))),
    "Share Path", 
        VAR fieldName = "Share Path"
        VAR idStart = SEARCH(fieldName, [RenderedDescription], , LEN(fieldName))
        VAR idEnd = SEARCH(" ", [RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName))
        RETURN IF(ISBLANK(idStart), BLANK(), MID([RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName), idEnd - idStart - LEN(fieldName))),
    "Access Request Information", 
        VAR fieldName = "Access Request Information"
        VAR idStart = SEARCH(fieldName, [RenderedDescription], , LEN(fieldName))
        VAR idEnd = SEARCH(" ", [RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName))
        RETURN IF(ISBLANK(idStart), BLANK(), MID([RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName), idEnd - idStart - LEN(fieldName))),
    "Access Mask", 
        VAR fieldName = "Access Mask"
        VAR idStart = SEARCH(fieldName, [RenderedDescription], , LEN(fieldName))
        VAR idEnd = SEARCH(" ", [RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName))
        RETURN IF(ISBLANK(idStart), BLANK(), MID([RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName), idEnd - idStart - LEN(fieldName))),
    "Accesses", 
        VAR fieldName = "Accesses"
        VAR idStart = SEARCH(fieldName, [RenderedDescription], , LEN(fieldName))
        VAR idEnd = SEARCH(" ", [RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName))
        RETURN IF(ISBLANK(idStart), BLANK(), MID([RenderedDescription], idStart + LEN(fieldName), idEnd - idStart - LEN(fieldName)))
)
```